# Can we change the Laplace equation to the wave equation with a linear substitution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, wave-equation

I would like to know, is it possible to make a **linear** change of **dependent** and **independent** variables such that Laplace's Equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy}$ transforms to the Wave Equation $\bar{u}_{\bar{x}\bar{x}}-\bar{u}_{\bar{y}\bar{y}}=0$. I believe the answer is no, and I have a rather involved method to calculate it, but, I'm curious how the community would approach this problem.

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: Well, that depends. Are you allowing a complex substitution?

Comment: real linear substitution. But, I am curious about what you mention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\xi = ax+by$, $\eta = cx+dy$ be the most general possible linear substitution. We want to find out what
$$ \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right) u = 0 $$
is in terms of $\xi$ and $\eta$. (Remark: there is actually no point in transforming both variables, but we may as well be as general as possible, just to be convincing.) (Further, this is rather poor notation, but it will do)

We have:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta} = a \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} + c \frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}, \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial y} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta} = b \frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} + d \frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}, $$
and hence
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = a \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\left( a \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} + c \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\right) + c \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} \left( a \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} + c \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta} \right) = a^2 u_{\xi\xi} + 2ac u_{\xi\eta} + c^2 u_{\eta\eta}, $$
and similarly
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = b^2 u_{\xi\xi} + 2bd u_{\xi\eta} + d^2 u_{\eta\eta}, $$
so we have
$$ (a^2+b^2)u_{\xi\xi} + 2(ac+bd)u_{\xi\eta} + (c^2+d^2)u_{\eta\eta} = 0 $$

Now, we want this to be equivalent to the wave equation, $u_{\xi\xi}-u_{\eta\eta}=0$, so we must have
$$ ac+bd = 0 \\
a^2+b^2 = -(c^2+d^2), $$
or
$$ a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=0 $$
Well, it's fairly clear what the problem is going to be here if we have a real change of variables: that last inequality can only hold if $a,b,c,d=0$, which is not an allowed substitution since you want $ad-bc \neq 0$ to have independence of the new variables, among other problems.

Therefore you can't do it with a real change of variables, but can with a complex one. The best exposition I've seen of this is [here](http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_5.pdf), which goes into far more generality than I have.

Comment: More generally, we required $ac+bd=0$ and $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)<0$.  And obviously, the second condition cannot be met with real-valued parameters.  Aside ... closing in on the magic 10,000 points!  Well Done.

Comment: I clarified that bit of the argument slightly to have the coefficients being equal (like the question asks). Yeah, the last 500 rep's proving to be a bit slow :S.

Comment: You'll get there.  But I have noticed a change in the types of questions that have appeared herein over the past month or so.  Perhaps this is a consequence of the school year cycle.

Comment: That's my thought too: everyone round here's digging in in exams at present. Where are the integrals of yesteryear? ;)

Comment: Pining for those days of "cool" analysis questions.